# Vue js Javascript контекст

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть задача касательно js, vuejs https://codepen.io/login2030/pen/VrxgPe. Объясните пожалуйста, почему задача решается правильно, если добавить `console.log(this.deleted)` или любую запись связанную с `this.deleted` во внутрь вычисляемого свойства count() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Почему не работает

Как говорится [в доках](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), Vue плохо справляется с изменениями внутри массивов. Изначально свойство `count` зависит только от `items.length`:

```
count() {
  return this.items.length;
}
```

Следовательно, это свойство должно актуализироваться только тогда, когда произойдет изменение в объектах, от которых оно зависит - т.е. в `items.length`. Массив `items` не изменяется явным образом, поэтому Vue не может отследить изменение в `items.length`. Поэтому свойство `count` не обновляется.

#### Почему работает с this.deleted

В отличие от `items`, массив `deleted` изменяется явно (`this.deleted = ...`), и такое изменение Vue может отследить. Поэтому, когда в свойство `count` добавляется еще одна зависимость (от `deleted`), и после этого делается `this.deleted = ...`, то Vue видит, что одна из зависимостей обновилась, и обновляет свойство `count`.